# How to build a molecule correctly in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I am building a methane molecule in three.js, I have drawn my molecule but when I try to run it in jsbin, I am not seeing the output. I am not sure if I have renderered it incorrectly. Thank you. Here is my code 
http://jsbin.com/tuqusip/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="Methane" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> Methane</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
</div>
</body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r58/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://simpletruthsforhealthyliving.com/js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


      // set the scene size
    var WIDTH = 500,
        HEIGHT = 500;

    // set some camera attributes
    var VIEW_ANGLE = 45,
        ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT,
        NEAR = 1,
        FAR = 1000;

    // get the DOM element to attach to
    // - assume we've got jQuery to hand
    var $container = $('#container');

    // create a WebGL renderer, camera
    // and a scene
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();


    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(  VIEW_ANGLE,
                                    ASPECT,
                                    NEAR,
                                    FAR  );                

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var clock = new THREE.Clock();

    // the camera starts at 0,0,0 so pull it back so we can see the whole object
    camera.position.z = 25;    

    // CONTROLS enables us to control the object with the mouse
    var cameraControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    cameraControls.addEventListener( 'mousemove', renderer );
    cameraControls.autoRotate = true;

    // start the renderer
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    // attach the render-supplied DOM element
    $container.append(renderer.domElement);



methanum3 = function(x, y, z) {


    molecule = new THREE.Object3D();
    var startPosition = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
    molecule.add(atom(startPosition, "c"));

    var axis = new THREE.AxisHelper( 50 );
    axis.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
    molecule.add( axis );

    var secondPosition = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -40 );
    molecule.add(atom(secondPosition, "h"));


    var angle = 109.5;
    var matrixX = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis( new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ), angle * ( Math.PI / 180 ));
    var thirdPosition = secondPosition.applyMatrix4( matrixX );
    molecule.add(atom(thirdPosition, "h"));

    var matrixZ = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationAxis( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 ), 120 * ( Math.PI / 180 ));

    var fourthPosition = thirdPosition.applyMatrix4( matrixZ );
    molecule.add(atom(fourthPosition, "h"));

    var fifthPosition = fourthPosition.applyMatrix4( matrixZ );
    molecule.add(atom(fifthPosition, "h"));

    molecule.position.set(x, y, z);
    //molecule.rotation.set(x, y, z);
    scene.add( molecule );
}

//water(0,0,0);
//water(30,60,0);
methanum3(-30,60,0);

// add the camera
    scene.add(camera)

    // create a point light
    var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight();

    // add to the scene
    scene.add(pointLight);

    // draw!
    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        render();
    }

    function render() {
        cameraControls.update();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    animate();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you have a jsbin, can you please share the link? Also: on a quick glance, this line looks odd: `cameraControls.addEventListener( 'mousemove', renderer );` (whatever you wanted to do here: it won't work as renderer is the `THREE.WebGLRenderer` instance and cannot be called as a function)

Comment: Here is  my jsbin link http://jsbin.com/tuqusip/edit?html,output. Thank you